# How to display development credits at the beginning of application?

Tags: android

When the application is opened i would like to display credits by to the user like maybe a screen with the company's logo and some other stuff. How do i go about doing this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Create a true splash screen](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6519649/create-a-true-splash-screen)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a very vague question. Credits screen can look different depending on the design.
Ive seen apps with their credits screen flipping between developers photos.

If your looking for something like that. This might help. 
https://github.com/blessenm/SlideshowDemo

If you are simply looking to start an activty at the beginning and automatically switch to another activity, create a SplashActivity in the beginning and show your credits layout.
In the onCreate function add the code

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable(){
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Intent appInitIntent = new    
        Intent(AppStart.this,com.AppInit.class);
                startActivity(appInitIntent);
                finish();
            }
}, 1000);
```

This will start another activity after 1000 ms automatically.