# How can I provide *immediate* confirmation of an app's execution when the main activity is transparent?

Tags: android

The main activity of my app is defined in the Android manifest file with the following attribute:

`android:theme="@style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"`

This makes the activity transparent, which in turn makes it possible to control the transparency of my app in code by manipulating the main View object (e.g., by invoking `setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE)` on the main view).  This works fine.

However, one undesirable consequence of this approach is that when the app is launched there is no visible response until my main View is displayed.  Normally, the default black background of an app's main activity is immediately visible when an app is launched, which provides immediate confirmation that the app is starting to run in response to the user tapping its icon in the launcher.  But with a transparent background, the user continues to look *through* the background at the display from which the app is being launched until the main view is displayed, and so it appears (during that interval) as if nothing has occurred.

Even on a device with mediocre performance (e.g., the Motorola Droid) my view comes up in about one second, which is not too bad.  However, on a really slow device (e.g., the G1) it can take almost four seconds.  While this is not a disaster, I'd prefer an immediate response so that the user is not left wondering whether the app was in fact triggered.

I have tried removing the transparent theme, which results in immediate confirmation via a black background, as usual.  However, I've been unable to set the activity background to transparent in code once the app has been initialized.

I've invoked `setTheme()` on the activity just prior to calling `setContentView()` for the first time, passing it a transparent theme, but this does not make the activity transparent.

I've also tried this in `onCreate()` (again, just prior to calling `setContentView()`):

```
ColorDrawable transparentDrawable = new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT);
getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(transparentDrawable);
```

This also appears to have no effect.

I've also tried using a theme in my manifest that has `android:windowBackground` set to a drawable that is a mostly transparent PNG, but with some text (e.g., the app's name) superimposed on the transparent background that would provide a cue to the user that the app was loading.  Unfortunately, the moment I use a drawable as part of the theme, the background fails to display at all until after the main view is initialized.

All time-consuming initializations are already being done in a worker thread, so I'm not looking for advice on how to accomplish that.  The view itself just takes a certain amount of time to display, and while it is fairly quick, nothing beats the instantaneous response of seeing the main activity's background as soon as the app is launched.

Comment: It's quite a "dirty" solution but you could add a "dummy/splash screen" activity with background that's the starting activity of your app. In onCreate you start your main activity and finish the splash screen activity

Comment: I tried that, but the result was that the splash screen activity never appeared; there was the usual delay and then my main activity appeared (invoked from onCreate() in the splash activity).  The splash activity was on the stack as expected, and was visible "behind" my main activity when I made its main view transparent; it just never got around to displaying prior to the main activity being displayed.

Comment: If this can be solved, my suspicion is that it will involve setting the main activity to be transparent somehow.  setTheme() is supposed to work if done prior to setContentView(), but I've been unable to make that happen, even when done at the top of onCreate().

Functionally, this isn't a huge deal for me, and I may have to put it aside for more pressing tasks, but I'm very interested in any suggestions that people might have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've upvoted CommonsWare's answer, because he pointed me in the right direction, which is away from trying to change the transparency of the main activity after it is launched (something I'm beginning to suspect cannot be easily done).

However, that advice cannot itself be the accepted answer, given that it is only a pointer in the right direction.

The answer I decided upon, given this guidance, was to create a splash display.  However, I could not find a truly good android splash example anywhere.  So, I devised one, and it is working very well for me, and completely solves my problem.

Because creating a splash display is a more general question than the one I started out with, I have placed my detailed description of how that can be done as an answer to a question about how to implement a splash screen, and have linked to that answer below:

[Create a true splash screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6519649/create-a-true-splash-screen/10202161#10202161)

Answer (score 1):

> Even on a device with mediocre performance (e.g., the Motorola Droid) my view comes up in about one second, which is not too bad. However, on a really slow device (e.g., the G1) it can take almost four seconds.

It should come up in milliseconds. Make sure you are not doing excessive work on the main application thread.

> The view itself just takes a certain amount of time to display, and while it is fairly quick, nothing beats the instantaneous response of seeing the main activity's background as soon as the app is launched.

Then initially display something else that is cheaper to bring up (e.g., `ProgressBar`), replacing it with your regular UI when it is ready.

Comment: On a G1, even if my app is sitting in background fully initialized, it takes 4 seconds to resume the display.  The G1 is just a slow device, and there are a lot of graphical elements (game board, controls) for it to refresh on my main display.  Even my G1 home screen icons take 4 seconds to appear.

I suspect that displaying a simple activity background uses a natively-coded loop, and if that background is transparent then there's a much longer wait before there is any visible effect.  So I'm looking for a way to make this background transparent *after* my app has initialized its display.

Comment: Nonetheless, I'll take another look at getting the view itself to display more quickly, per your suggestion.  I'd be perfectly happy with a quick black or white background display, followed by my main display, given that I'm requiring API 8 at a minimum and most devices running Froyo are going to be able to be powerful enough to bring up the main view in less than a second.  But if that cannot be done while preserving transparency, then working on initializing the view itself more quickly as you've suggested could improve the speed of the initial response somewhat.

Comment: @Carl: "Even my G1 home screen icons take 4 seconds to appear." -- then your G1 is sick. I owned and used a G1 for a couple of years and never had that kind of performance problem.

Comment: Quite possibly so!  The problem remains, however, in concept, even though its severity may have been magnified by a sick device.  My Droid, for example, seems to be working fine, but there is still that nagging one-second delay on startup.

Per your suggestion, I will look at putting up a quick-displaying "splash" view, to be replaced by my main view when ready, rather than relying upon an opaque activity background to provide immediate confirmation of launch.  Will post back if that works out.