# Creating a splash screen in android (for noob)

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Create a true splash screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6519649/create-a-true-splash-screen)

Can someone point me to a tutorial where I can learn how to make a splash screen for my app. Like Splash screens for dummies.

Answer (score 1):

This here may help you :

http://www.jameselsey.co.uk/blogs/techblog/how-to-add-a-splash-screen-to-your-android-application-in-under-5-minutes/

Or this : 
http://www.droidnova.com/how-to-create-a-splash-screen,561.html